# Spring Data Rest Add All Projections In A Package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using `RepositoryConfig` in order to register my [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) for Spring Data Rest.
All projections in the same package. Is there an easy way to add all projections to configuration. Instead of [addProjection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/ProjectionDefinitionConfiguration.html#addProjection-java.lang.Class-) for each class. Is there a Reflection solution or a Spring-based solution to add all Projection in a package?

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.getProjectionConfiguration()
                .addProjection(PurchaseProjection.class)
                .addProjection(OrderProjection.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a reflection library from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520339/7885651) question.
Via [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library here is my solution:

```
 public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
    // Scan all projections and add them in to the configuration.
    Reflections r= new Reflections("com.company.projection");
    for (Class<?> c: r.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Projection.class)) {
      config.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(c);
    }
  }
```